# How to receive Shopify Webhook?

Tags: webhooks, shopify-app

Below is my code.

```
define('SHOPIFY_APP_SECRET', 'xxxxxxxxxx');

function verify_webhook($data, $hmac_header)
{
  $calculated_hmac = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $data, SHOPIFY_APP_SECRET, true));
  return hash_equals($hmac_header, $calculated_hmac);
}


$hmac_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_HMAC_SHA256'];
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$verified = verify_webhook($data, $hmac_header);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
exit;   

?>
```

I've registered the app/uninstalled webhook.
So this is my code but not receiving any response

Comment: If you're not receiving a webhook request (not response), then your signature validation code doesn't provide any help in determining what the problem is. There are a very wide variety of issues that might interfere with getting the request. I would suggest you try the Shopify community forum as they are quite good about helping people with webhook implementation issues.

Comment: Hey, @dmulter right now I'm getting request (not response) of my webhook. The issue is with my "SHOPIFY_APP_SECRET" Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a late answer. But might helpful for the future user who will land here. You forgot to save the `response` you are getting from `uninstall webhook` to somewhere. Considered saving `response` to file. here is php code to save. After saving the response you can read or do processing after that.

```
file_put_contents($newFileName, $data);
```

Also, save the response only when `HMAC hash` matched you got from api. You can get `domain name` and for which `topic` api is fired. below is code. Do the necessary work.

```
$domain = $_SERVER['X-Shopify-Shop-Domain'];
$topic = $_SERVER['X-Shopify-Topic'];
```

Let me know if you are looking for more detail. thanks